# SQL Query to to acces Excel data - Java

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to read from excel using Fillo-1.18. Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fillo fillo=new Fillo();
        Connection connection;
        try {
            connection = fillo.getConnection("C:\\Users\\Dish\\Desktop\\1.xlsx");

            String strQuery="Select sum(Amount) as amnt, Run_ID from Sheet1 group by Run_ID";
            Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(strQuery);

            while(recordset.next()){
                System.out.println(recordset.getField("amnt"));
            }

            recordset.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (FilloException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It works fine for normal select clause. But when I am trying to use aggregate functions like SUM(), I am not able to access that field. Inside `while` I am get the following error:

```
com.codoid.products.exception.FilloException: amnt field is not found
    at com.codoid.products.fillo.Recordset.getField(Recordset.java:163)
    at ReadExcelSheetData.main(ReadExcelSheetData.java:18)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I'm presuming that you are getting records in your record set? Also, have you looked at the columns in your recordset?

Comment: Try using some framework like POI. Avoid reading Excel files directly.

Comment: @reflexdemon - But POI doesn't give the option to sort right?

Comment: @Zac - Yes. If I do `recordset.getFieldNames()`, I can get AMNT as a field name. But when I try to get the value of it, I get the above error.

Comment: Try changing this: `System.out.println(recordset.getField("amnt"));` to : `System.out.println(recordset.getField("AMNT"));`